# why $\frac{1}{z}$ is the universal counterexample to converse of morera

Tags: complex-analysis

the last paragraph in the intro of this article ([Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)) says:

> In a certain sense, the $\frac{1}{z}$ counterexample is universal: For every analytic function that has no antiderivative on its domain, the reason for this is that $\frac{1}{z}$ itself does not have an antiderivative on $\mathbb{C} − \{0\}$.

i'm not exactly sure what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: If you have a meromorphic function without an antiderivative at 0, you can find a constant $a$ so that you can locally write $f(z)=a/z+g(z)$ where $g(z)$ does have an antiderivative.  The only thing that is causing trouble is some multiple of $1/z$ which can be subtracted off.

Comment: This is stated too broadly, but what they mean is that around any pole one can expand a meromorphic function into a [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series), and the only term in it whose anti-derivative is not analytic is $\frac{1}{z}$.